# jQuery Ajax - downloading incomplete (binary) file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is what I have:

```
jquery/1.10.2

$.ajax({
    url: "http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf",
    dataType: "text",
    data: "",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.length);
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {}
});
```

When I run that locally (in Safari 6.0.5 on OS X), I get 211300. However, the actual file appears to be 218882 bytes. With something fully ASCII (such as http://www.angio.net/pi/digits/pi1000000.txt), it seems to work correctly.

I don't need to download the file, but rather, work with its content.

Is there any way to make ajax work with binary files (either client side or server side) without resorting to using base64?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do this client side rather than server side ?

Comment: I'm using it for client side encryption/decryption, so everything's binary. I'm using the PDF as an example since it's easiest I can reproduce the error.

Comment: Are you using `GET` or `POST` ?

Comment: Are you rebuilding HTTPS manually? Otherwise, server side is the only secure method here - client side code will be easy to decipher.

Comment: This scenario must be handled using server side coding and not client side scripting , other wise basic `XSS` might be an issue here.

Comment: 1.10.2 but also tested on 2.0.3

Comment: btw client side encryption is not safe at all. What if javascript is intercepted and modiefied, then encryption won't be foul proof. Only way to do it is use https. But if you are using https then why bother with another layer of encryption that will end along https. So if https gets broken then it gets broken and if not then it's just extra work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use **typed arrays**. Javascript way of dealing with binary.
There is no other way to deal with pure binary data. But with typed arrays you can do almost everything that you would want to do with binary anywhere else.

### Sending Typed Array using Ajax

```
var myArray = new ArrayBuffer(512);
var longInt8View = new Uint8Array(myArray);

for (var i=0; i< longInt8View.length; i++) {
  longInt8View[i] = i % 255;
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("POST", url, false);
xhr.send(myArray);
```

### Receiving Typed Array

2 ways to do it...**First**

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
      // do something with each byte in the array
    }
  }
};

oReq.send(null);
```

**Second**

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "image/png"});
  // ...
};

oReq.send();
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

### Using Jquery

**Sending:** `$.ajax(url,{data:myArray});`

**Receiving:**  not tested...

```
$.ajax('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/coffee.png',{
    contentType: "arraybuffer",
    success: function(d){
        var blob = new Blob([d], {type: "image/png"}),
            u = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
});
```

Comment: But can one have jQuery send/receive data as a typed array? (And if so, how?)

Comment: A good detailed answer, but the question was specifically about jQuery - is it possible to do these things with jQuery, or must one resolve to the native XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

**The worst wheel of the cart makes the most noise!**
 ***go for a better solution here***

http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

**Demo here**

http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

**Fully tested on:** 
Internet Explorer 6 – 9 
Firefox 11 – reasonably sure it will work on earlier versions 
Chrome 17 – reasonably sure it will work on earlier versions

**Remark : jQuery 1.3+ needed.**

**update:**

**Haven't tried though**

```
$.ajax({
url: controllerUrl,
type: 'Get',
 contentType: "application/pdf",
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=UTF-8')
 //alert({ message: "Processing..." });
},
success: function (data) 
{ alert('Wga!'); 
 },
 complete: function (data) {
 alert('close');                                  
 },
error: function (jqXHR,textStatus) 
{ alert("whoops");    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually need to work with the content as I'm doing some browser-side encryption. I used the PDF file as an example since it's binary and jQuery seemed to have issues with binary data.