# MVC download file through AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, download

I want to allow users to choose a file to download from a drop down list. Once they have made a selection, they can click the download button. However, the file does not download correctly.

Here is the controller for generating and returning the file:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadReport(int? id, string templateChoice)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        try
        {
            byte[] file = GetReport(id, templateChoice);
            return File(file, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "ResumeReport.docx");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The JavaScript function which is called upon pressing the generate report button is:

```
function downloadReport(InputID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadReport", "UserProfiles")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "ID": InputID, "TemplateChoice": $("#resumeTemplates").val() }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
    }
```

Opening the inspect window in chrome and going to the network tab shows the document data is received, but it does not download like a regular file.

Comment: you are not getting JSON from server, it's binary. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18450007/4607796

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have found a working solution which does **not** reload page, does not redirect the user, and does not show any excess text in the URL upon pressing the download button. I replaced my current JavaScript function with the following:

```
function downloadReport(inputID) {
        window.location.href = '/UserProfiles/DownloadReport/?id=' + inputID + '&template=' + $('#resumeTemplates').val();
    }
```

And my controller now looks like:

```
public ActionResult DownloadReport(int? id, string template)
    {
        if (id == null || template == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        try
        {
            byte[] file = GetReport(id, template);
            return File(file, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "ResumeReport.docx");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I also added this into my RouteConfig.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "DownloadReport",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{template}",
            new { controller = "UserProfiles", action = "DownloadReport", id = UrlParameter.Optional, template = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```